# React Json Schema Form - Anyof no se autocompleta con formData

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, formularios

estamos utilizando json schemas complejos que definen la interacción entre una react app y un backend en django. En el schema utilizamos la propiedad anyof para elegir si tenemos una propiedad o no. Por ejemplo definamos el siguiente schema:

```
{
  'type':'object',
  'properties':{
    'prop1': {
      'title': 'has prop1?'
      'anyOf':[
        {'title':'No', 'type':'null'},
        {'title': 'yes', '$ref':'#/definitions/prop1'}
      ]
    }
  },
  'definitions':{
    'prop1':{
      'title':'Property 1',
      'type': 'object',
      'properties':{
         'a':{'title': 'A', 'type':'number'},
         'b':{'title': 'B', 'type':'number'},
      }
    }
  }
}
```

El problema ocurre cuando en formData se le entrega la variable prop1. No siempre estará seleccionado, pero si se elige yes los datos serán visibles. Probamos muchas soluciones pero ninguna nos parecio correcta o que sean buenas practicas.

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Bienvenido, este es el sitio de StackOverflow en **español**, deberías editar tu pregunta y traducirla.

Comment: @RogerTorné gracias! Ahi lo tradujimos.